# Freemarker nested macros

Tags: freemarker

How can I call nested macros as such?

```
<@replaceA-sToB-s>
   <@replaceB-sToC-s Text/>
</@replaceA-sToB-s>
```

replaceB-sToC-s simply replaces any "B" with "C"
replaceA-sToB-s simply replaces any "A" with "B"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the result of `replaceB-sToC-s` macro to the `replaceA-sToB-s` then you have to use something like this:

```
<#assign str><@replaceB-sToC-s "abc" /></#assign> 
<@replaceA-sToB-s str />
```

Comment: You don't have to capture around each `@replaceBsToCs` call. Instead, you can do that inside `@replaceAsToBs`. But see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<#macro replaceAsToBs>
  <#local captured><#nested></#local>
  ${captured?replace('a', 'b')}<#t>
</#macro>

<#macro replaceBsToCs text>
  ${text?replace('b', 'c')}<#t>
</#macro>
```

(The `#t`-s are only there to remove the extra whitespace around the `${...}` parts.) And then you call it like:

```
<@replaceAsToBs>
   <@replaceBsToCs "abcd"/>
</@replaceAsToBs>
```